# Join multiple data frames based on date

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to join all three files based on `Time`. I want to add `NA` if the data frame does not have a value for that particular date. In total, there should be 7 columns in the output.

```
> head(Dax1,3)
        Time      Res     Accum
1 2017-10-20  1174.60 172278.21
2 2017-10-18  -109.41 171103.61
3 2017-08-28 -2670.84 171213.02
> head(Dax2,3)
        Time     Res     Accum
1 2017-10-23 1473.25 185076.53
2 2017-08-24 1001.50 183603.28
3 2017-07-31 -144.96 182601.79
> head(Dax3,3)
        Time     Res      Accum
1 2017-11-07 -348.37 189 023.90
2 2017-10-26  398.16 189 372.27
3 2017-10-25  -80.19 188 974.10
```

I tried `join_all` but it seems to jon them in a long-format. I want them side-by-side as 7 columns in total:

```
> join_all(list, by = "Time",match = "all",type="full")
        Time      Res      Accum
1 2017-10-20  1174.60  172278.21
2 2017-10-18  -109.41  171103.61
3 2017-08-28 -2670.84  171213.02
4 2017-10-23  1473.25  185076.53
5 2017-08-24  1001.50  183603.28
6 2017-07-31  -144.96  182601.79
7 2017-11-07  -348.37 189 023.90
8 2017-10-26   398.16 189 372.27
9 2017-10-25   -80.19 188 974.10
```

Comment: `rbind(Dax1, Dax2, Dax3)`    You may want to resort afterwards

Comment: @G5W Probaby `cbind` you meant?

Comment: cbind creates 3 output rows. there are more unique dates in the inputs.

Comment: Try creating unique column names i.e. `plyr::join_all(Map(function(x,y) {names(x)[-1] <- paste0(names(x)[-1], y); x}, lst, seq_along(lst)), by = "Time",match = "all",type="full")`

Comment: @akrun  You are right.  I misread the question.  But cbind won't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could rename the columns of the datasets in the `list` except the 'Time' column and apply the `join_all`

```
res1 <- plyr::join_all(Map(function(x,y) {
         names(x)[-1] <- paste0(names(x)[-1], y)
         x}, lst, seq_along(lst)), by = "Time",match = "all",type="full")
```

---

Or this can be done in a chain using some of the functions from `tidyverse`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
res2 <- lst %>%
          map2(., seq_along(.), ~setNames(.x, c('Time', paste0(names(.x)[-1], .y)))) %>% 
          plyr::join_all(., by = 'Time', match = 'all', type = 'full')

identical(res1, res2)
#[1] TRUE
```